# Вывод одного вопроса из XML рандомно

Tags: xml, actionscript

Здравствуйте! Написал небольшой код для викторины. Игра будет заключаться в том, что нужно будет правильно ответить на вопрос, выбрав один из четырёх вариантов ответа. Есть фрагмент кода:

```
 var xml:XML = new XML();
 trace(xml.child("q").length());
 trace(xml.child("q")[Math.round(Math.random()*10)].toXMLString());
```

Подключение XML-файла тоже есть и работает. В данном коде пытаюсь вывести тэг <q> и его дочерние тэги, причём сделать это методом выбора одного из 10. Но почему-то метод не работает, подскажите, как это можно осуществить ещё?

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте так

`trace(xml.child("q")[Math.floor(Math.random() * xml.child("q").length())]);`